# Android Eclipse remove a library project jar

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to remove one of the jar folders from my library project. When I click on the jar folder the options to remove it are greyed out.

I would like to remove the mopub-android-sdk.jar

[image]

Here are the options it gives me. Why is everything greyed out?

[image]

Anyone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to project properties -> Android -> In the bottom part, remove the appropriate library project

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer didn't work for me - my jar wasn't listed in that screen.  Here's what worked for me:

Remove the jar from the libs/ folder, then select the project, then refresh (F5 or right-click on the project and select "refresh").